# How to dpm() the Drupal.settings.basePath var

Tags: debugging

For debugging purposes I need to use dpm to output the value of Drupal.settings.basePath. I tried this (but not working):

```
dpm(Drupal.settings.basePath); // not working
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Drupal.settings.basePath` is a value available from JavaScript, as Clive said, while `dpm()` is a PHP function. If you look at [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7), you will notice that value is set using the following code.

```
  $javascript = array(
    'settings' => array(
      'data' => array(
        array('basePath' => base_path()),
        array('pathPrefix' => empty($prefix) ? '' : $prefix),
      ), 
      'type' => 'setting', 
      'scope' => 'header', 
      'group' => JS_LIBRARY, 
      'every_page' => TRUE, 
      'weight' => 0,
    ), 
    'misc/drupal.js' => array(
      'data' => 'misc/drupal.js', 
      'type' => 'file', 
      'scope' => 'header', 
      'group' => JS_LIBRARY, 
      'every_page' => TRUE, 
      'weight' => -1, 
      'preprocess' => TRUE, 
      'cache' => TRUE, 
      'defer' => FALSE,
    ),
  );
```

If you want to get in PHP the value assigned to `Drupal.settings.basePath` in JavaScript, you just use `dpm(base_path())`. Clive's answer already tells you how to print the JavaScript value from JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

`Drupal.settings.basePath` is a javascript variable, not PHP...you can't access it on the server side like that.

I imagine the output you're getting in the message area is 'DrupalsettingsbasePath', which is how PHP would interpret `Drupal.settings.basePath`, along with a few PHP Notices complaining about the use of an undefined constant.

Assuming you're using a browser that supports `console.log`, to debug the base path just add the following in a javascript file that's included in your page:

```
console.log(Drupal.settings.basePath);
```

The variable will then be printed to your browser's console area.